# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when i trying use strtok in C

Tags: c, strtok, string.h

```
#define delims "\t"
char **parser(char *line)
{
  int position = 0;
  char **tokens = malloc(64* sizeof(char*));
  char *token;

  token = strtok(line, delims);
  while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;

    token = strtok(NULL, delims);
  }
  tokens[position] = NULL;
  return tokens;
}

int main(){
  char **args;
  char *line="abc\tabc";
  args=parser(line);
}
```

When i try to run this code, i am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. I tried this on linux with gcc. Problem is not about tokens' size.

Comment: compiler just replace the delims with "\t", which is not a pointer, instead use new std::string("\t");

Comment: `"abc\tabc"` is a string literal, a `const char[]` and that `const` is extremely important. `strtok` is going to try to change that constant string, and changing constant data is something you ought not do. Because often you can't.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Huh? `strtok` doesn't know about `std::string()`. Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: well use std::string("\t").c_str() so you get a char *

Comment: C or C++?  Pick **one** for a problem like this as they are not the same language and the proper answer will differ.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia The `c_str()` member returns a `const char*`, not `char*` (thus the `c` in `c_str()`. All that should be required for this OP is chaning `char *line = ` to `char line[] = `.

Comment: ` const_cast<char *>(std::string("\t").c_str()) ` better?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have removed the C++ tag, because the code wouldn't even compile in C++ as the return value of `malloc` can not be cast to `char**` implicitly in C++.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia ignore all the casting etc: which bit are you saying `"\t"` doesn't work for? There is no problem with `"\t"` usage in OPs code (if there is, then I've missed it and you should explain it better)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia best to avoid that approach. The `string` is made a bit weird when `strtok` embeds a bunch of nulls in it. A C++ solution to this problem would include `std::vector` and `std::stringstream` or `string::find` and `string::substr` and look almost completely different. No point trying to force `strtok` into it.

Answer (score 3):

The `strtok` function modifies the string it tokenizes.  You're passing in a pointer to a string literal, and string literals are read only.  Attempting to modify them invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes a crash.

Change `line` to an array so that it can be modified.

```
char line[]="abc\tabc";
```

Comment: Loop though it to read, just like you do to write, until you see the NULL pointer at the end.

Comment: the tokens pointed at by `args` will still be valid so long as `line` is in scope. Keep `line` alive and you can read `args` until the cows come home.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

In

```
char *line="abc\tabc";
```

`"abc\tabc"` is a string literal, a `const char[8]` and that `const` is extremely important. Writing to `const` data invokes undefined behaviour because it should not be changed. Often this is accidentally enforced by storing it in non-writable storage.

`strtok` is a destructive function. It is going to try to insert null characters between each token and it cannot do this if the string is in non-writable storage.

## Solution:

Allocate some non-constant storage

```
char line[] = "abc\tabc";
```